# how to print \0 to stdout in swift

Tags: macos, swift2, chrome-native-messaging

I am writing a native messaging extension for chrome, and as per the protocol I need to output the first 4 bytes as the length of the data that is to follow.

If I do this in Objective C, it works:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        char data[] = "{\"payload\":\"19\"}";
        int len = strlen(data);

        printf("%c%c%c%c",
               (char)((len>>0) & 0xff),
               (char)((len>>8) & 0xff),
               (char)((len>>16) & 0xff),
               (char)((len>>24) & 0xff));
        printf("%s", data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The best translation I can make of it to Swift is as follows:

```
import Foundation

var data:String

data = "{\"payload\": \"100\"}"

var length:Int
length = data.characters.count

print(String(format: "%c", (UInt8)((length >> 0) & 0xff)), terminator:"")
print(String(format: "%c", (UInt8)((length >> 8) & 0xff)), terminator:"")
print(String(format: "%c", (UInt8)((length >> 16) & 0xff)), terminator:"")
print(String(format: "%c", (UInt8)((length >> 24) & 0xff)), terminator:"")
print(data, terminator:"")
fflush(__stdoutp)
```

This shows an error in the chrome log:

```
[458:33283:0524/103231:ERROR:native_message_process_host.cc(292)]
Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 1881307922 bytes long.
```

What is happening is that the first byte is getting printed, but the remain three bytes have a value of zero and thus translate to the NUL character which is obviously the end of string character and thus nothing is getting printed.  If I change the first three letters of the data (`{"p`) then that number `1881307922` also changes, which confirms that the first four bytes being read to determine the length of the message are these, and the three NUL bytes are not getting printed.

I would like a solution that deviates very little from what I am doing right now.  There are a lot of other things in the application that I have not shown, if you propose a solution that is very different then it would mean that I would have to rewrite a lot of other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `String(format:` part with `Character(UnicodeScalar(`, like this:

```
import Foundation

var data:String

data = "{\"payload\": \"100\"}"

var length:Int
length = data.characters.count

print(Character(UnicodeScalar((UInt8)((length >> 0) & 0xff))), terminator:"")
print(Character(UnicodeScalar((UInt8)((length >> 8) & 0xff))), terminator:"")
print(Character(UnicodeScalar((UInt8)((length >> 16) & 0xff))), terminator:"")
print(Character(UnicodeScalar((UInt8)((length >> 24) & 0xff))), terminator:"")
print(data, terminator:"")
fflush(__stdoutp)
```